# Web caching with fallback and SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, node.js

What would be the best way, or the different ways of caching data from an API for x minutes, with fallback to the last cache if api is down ?

My situation:

- I have a website (running with apache) that display the next football matches
- I get data from an API (data provider)
- I want to cache the request so I don't exceed API limit
- If the data provider is down I need to still be able to display data from last cache

Is there anyway to do this ? Or more what would be the best way ?

Can I do this with a nodejs server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what kind of data you handle, you have multiple `datastore` that can help, such as `memcached`, `redis` and many others. If your application is done with `nodeJS` you can connect to these various datastores, most of them will provide interfaces to connect from various languages.

In short, your problem is quite standard, and your answers will depend a lot on specifics of your problem space, such as volume of data, kind of persistence you need, if you have multiple servers and a need to maintain some consistency, the format of your data, etc.